# 'str' object is not applicable

Tags: python, string

I have the following little function written in Python:

```
def encode(str):
    out = ""
    for i in str:
        ret += str(ord(i.upper()) - 64)
    return ret
```

Basically, what I want to do is get the number of the letter in the alphabat and concatenate it to the 'out' string. With this code I get a traceback at line 4: 'str' object is not applicable.

Could someone please explain me why it throws this error and how I can fix this? (Sorry if this was already asked once, I couldn't find it, probably also because I'm pretty new to Python and programming)

Comment: str is also a built-in function so the interpreter isn't able to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never name your variable on the pre-defined built-in name.

In your code, `str` is not a built-in function. It's the variable you have used as parameter in your function.

Another problem is, you have declared `out` variable, and using `ret` which will give you error. Change `out = ""` to `ret = ""`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call your variable `str`, you're shadowing the [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Also, you need to fix the naming of `out`/`ret`.

I personally would write this function as follows:

```
def encode(s):
   return ''.join(str(ord(c.upper()) - 64) for c in s)
```

(I don't really follow what the `str(ord(...))` is meant to be doing, so I've just copied it from your code.)

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, do not use `str` as a variable.

I suspect this is what you want though:

```
def encode(s):
    return "".join(chr(ord(c.upper()) - 64) for c in s)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def encode(s):
    out = ""
    for c in s:
        ret += chr(ord(c.upper()) - 64)
    return ret
```

You were looking for the `chr()` function, which converts a numerical ASCII/Unicode value into a 1-character string. Running `str()` would convert `5` to `"5"`.

Also on a stylistic note, it's customary to do `for c in s` when iterating over a string, and `for i in x` when iterating over a sequence of integers.